# Spring security Jwt bearer token encoding/decoding error

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt, bearer-token

When trying to validate a jwt bearer token from a user I'am getting a 403 error and the headers are telling me that my token has insufficent scope.I'am wondering where I went wrong in the process of encoding the scope,or if the way im decoding tokens is incorrect.

**Security Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    private final RSAKeyConfig keys;
    public SecurityConfiguration(RSAKeyConfig keys) {
        this.keys = keys;
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(UserDetailsService detailsService) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoProvider.setUserDetailsService(detailsService);
        daoProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return new ProviderManager(daoProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated());



        http
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtConverter())));


        http
                .sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));



        return http.build();


    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        System.out.print("decoder");
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(keys.getPublicKey()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(keys.getPublicKey())
                .privateKey(keys.getPrivateKey()).build();
        JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));

        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);

    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtConverter() {
        System.out.println("jwt converter");
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("Roles_");
        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtconverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtconverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);

        return jwtconverter;

    }


}
```

**Token Service**

```
@Service
public class TokenService {

    @Autowired
    private JwtEncoder jwtEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

    public String generateJwt(Authentication auth) {

        Instant now = Instant.now();

        String scope = auth.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

        JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
                .issuer("self")
                .issuedAt(now)
                .subject(auth.getName())
                .claim("roles", scope)
                .build();

        System.out.print(claims);

        return jwtEncoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claims))
.getTokenValue();

    }
}
```

**Key configuration**

```
@Component
@Data
public class RSAKeyConfig {

    private RSAPublicKey publicKey;

    private RSAPrivateKey privateKey;

    public RSAKeyConfig(){
        KeyPair pair = KeyGenerator.generateRsaKey();
        this.publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) pair.getPublic();
        this.privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) pair.getPrivate();
    }
}
```

**Key Generator**

```
public class KeyGenerator {

    public static KeyPair generateRsaKey(){


        KeyPair keyPair;

        try{
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

        return keyPair;

    }
}
```

I've tried tinkering with the security filter chain but that seems to be futile.
**relevent dependencies im using**
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aeshq.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su3Ku.png)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see your JWT has defined scope, not role - the authorization process is expecting a scope check (as authority), not a role check?

```
.requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

Try changing this line to:

```
.requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_ADMIN")
```

Comment: I tried that man and it didnt work